# How to create an integer array within a recursion?

Tags: python, arrays

The following code tries to create an integer array filled with `n` times number 1.

```
import sys

def foo(n):
    if n == 0:
        return []
    else:
        return foo(n-1).append(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo(5)
```

Executing this program yields in an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

What am I doing wrong when creating the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your `else`-clause. `append` does not return a new list, but rather adds an element to the list in-place, and then returns `None` (hence your error). Try this instead,

```
return foo(n-1) + [1]  # creates a *new* list
```

Comment: Unless there's really a reason to create a new list, this is going to waste a lot of time making a copy of the list at every recursion level. Better to just make it three lines of code and save the hassle; `result = foo(n-1)` `result.append(1)` `return result`

Comment: @HenryKeiter Of course there are much better ways to do this (e.g. *not* using recursion in the first place). I was just illustrating what was wrong with the OP's code.

Answer (score 5):

Just look at the following code to understand why you are getting the error,

```
>>> x = [].append(1)
>>> x is None
True
```

When you append to a list, the return value is `None`! So you must do something like this,

```
def foo(n):
    if n == 0:
        return []
    else:
        return foo(n-1) + [1]
```

Using `+` operator is really like calling `extend` on a list for which the return value *is the new list*, unlike `append`.

```
>>> x = [1] + [1]
>>> x
[1, 1]
```

**NOTE:** Obviously for this simple example you should just use,

```
>>> [1] * 6
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Which is fine for immutable `int`s but if you are dealing with objects where you don't want references to the same one,

```
>>> [1 for _ in range(6)]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

But I'm assuming you are writing this to practice recursive solutions and such.

Comment: Funnier way to initialize the list: `list(itertools.repeat(1, 6))`

Answer (score 3):

it might be worth noting that python has some nice syntax to cover your usecase:

```
>>> [1]*5
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: ...unless you're trying to use this as an opportunity to learn about recursion.  :)

Comment: Unless you're explicitly trying to learn about recursion, of course :)

Answer (score 1):

Your program, slightly changed

```
import sys

def foo(n):
    if n == 0:
        return []
    else:
        return foo(n-1) + [1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(foo(5))
```

Prints

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

`list.append()` modifies the list, but doesn't return anything.  So recursions of your function that reach that branch actually return nothing or `None`.

The method I listed appends an element to the list, and then returns the list, so your recursion works just as you had wanted.

Comment: I post the answer, then edit in the explanation, refresh in a few seconds.

Comment: @Marcin: haters gonna hate... +1 for me.

Comment: @Marcin, Downvoting competing answers -- classy.

Comment: @jedwards If an answer isn't useful, I downvote it. Feel free to downvote mine if you think describing the actual issue isn't useful.

Comment: Certainly then you remove the downvote when the answer was edited to "be helpful", no?

Comment: @jedwards Actually, I can't.

Answer (score -3):

`append` returns `None`. This is the problem.